# Python Azure Functions Identity-Based Connection for Trigger Bindings

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, queue

I can't seem to find clear documentation on how to set a System-assigned Managed Identity-based connection for my Queue-triggered Azure Function.

**Steps taken**:

1. Enabled System-assigned Managed Identity (SAMI) for the Azure Function
2. On the Queue Storage Account, granted the SAMI `Storage Queue Data Reader` and `Storage Queue Data Message Processor` Roles per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=queue&pivots=programming-language-csharp#grant-permission-to-the-identity).
3. Ensured the Extension Version is `5.0.0` or later

```
"extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
```

4. Added a `connection` value to the Function's `function.json` file:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "my-q",
      "connection": "QUEUE_CONN"
    }
  ]
}
```

5. Added a `QUEUE_CONN__queueServiceUri` app setting to the Function's `local.settings.json` file per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483728/azure-durable-functions-identity-based-queuetrigger-binding-queueserviceuri) SO question, which references [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#identity-based-connections) doc.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "QUEUE_CONN__queueServiceUri": "https://<my-q-storage>.queue.core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

- After `func azure functionapp publish <my-function> --publish-local-settings`, and writing the appropriate setting to Azure...the function will not trigger when adding a new queue.

6. I also tried adding `QUEUE_CONN__managedIdentityResourceId` per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=queue&pivots=programming-language-csharp#common-properties-for-identity-based-connections) (contradicting?) doc. But this didn't seem to trigger the Function upon adding a queue.
7. Also tried adding `"QUEUE_CONN__credential": "managedidentity"`. Still unable to trigger the function.

I'd really like to get away from dealing with a Key Vault secret when all other connections within the function rely on SAMI auth.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Even I received the same error code as yours, In order to make this Queue Trigger with managed Identity work, I have tried two methods and both of them worked successfully:-

***Approach 1:-***

My Local Function code:-

***function.json:-***

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "queue1",
      "connection": "valleystrg1_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

****init*.py:-***

```py
import logging

from azure.functions import QueueMessage


def main(msg: QueueMessage) -> None:
    logging.info('Python queue trigger function processed a queue item: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

***local.settings.json:-***

Note- settings from ***local.settings.json*** does not get uploaded to Function App configuration settings, As the local.settings.json file is ***.gitignored***.

***My Function App configuration settings:-***

***Note-*** My deployed **`function.json`** has **`valleystrg1_STORAGE`** in the connection as it is, I have just edited the **`Connection String`** in ***Configuration application setting*** like below:-

```
valleystrg1_STORAGE__queueServiceUri:https://valleystrg1.queue.core.windows.net
```

[image]

[image]

Provided **`Storage Queue  Data Contributor`** role to my **Function App** **managed Identity** on ***Storage account*** level which has my queue:-

[image]

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Approach 2:-***

***Portal:-***

I have directly created a ***Queue Trigger*** via ***Portal*** Edit:-

[image]

```
valleystrg2_STORAGE__queueServiceUri:https://valleystrg2.queue.core.windows.net
```

***My function.json:-***

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "queue1",
      "connection": "valleystrg2_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Added The function app managed identity Storage Queue Data Contributor role at Storage account level:-

[image]

***Output:-***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed screenshots. Just an FYI, you *can* publish the key/value pairs in your `local.settings.json` file as App Settings by using `func azure functionapp publish <your-function-app-name> --publish-local-settings`. You need to be mindful of which values you publish.

Comment: Worked for me. I was missing the correct RBAC permission. I had `Storage Queue Data Processor` instead of `Storage Queue Data Contributor`. Thanks again.